# Add an event with fullCalendar using a form

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add an event using fullCalendar. Here is my add_event.php . I have first a form where a user can put information like the title of the event, start date, end date , ect.. and after the form I have this jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function add_event()
    {  
        var form = $('#calendar').serialize();

        $.ajax({   
                type : 'POST',  
                url: '<?php echo site_url()."/public/calendar/addEvent" ?>',
                method: 'post',
                data: form,
                success: function(data)
                {   
                     if(data == 'true')
                       {   
                          var event = {
                        title : "AJAX",
                        start : "2012-08-16",
                        end   : "2012-08-17"
                           };

                                              $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true )
                     }                  
                     else
                    {   
                        // Display error
                    }  
            }


        });
    document.write('end');}

</script>
```

Now I just hard code the "add event", "end" is printed but the event isn't added to the calendar. What I am doing wrong?
Also, I would like to know how can the controller send the values of start date, end date , ect ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's wrong here?

Comment: when I put the jquery code just after the TODO, it doesn't show anything (white page)

Comment: @ganeshk when I put the jquery code just after the TODO, it doesn't show anything (white page)